# Simulate WCF behavior in a C# class for run triggers before method's calls

Tags: c#, wcf

I've a WCF service with a custom attribute for do something before method's calls.

Attribute class:

```
   /// <summary>
   /// Indica que un método va a ejecutar la validación del token antes de ejecutarse
   /// </summary>
   public class TokenValidationRequiredAttribute : ValidationRequiredAttribute
   {
      /// <summary>
      /// Crear un nuevo Invoker personalizado para la validación del token
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="operationDescription"></param>
      /// <param name="dispatchOperation"></param>
      public override void ApplyDispatchBehavior (OperationDescription operationDescription, DispatchOperation dispatchOperation)
      {
         // Se crea un nuevo invocador de la operación que será el encargado de validar el token.
         // Se le pasa el invocador original.
         dispatchOperation.Invoker = new TokenValidationInvoker (operationDescription.Name, dispatchOperation.Invoker);
      }
   }
```

ValidationRequiredAttribute is a custom class inherits Attribute and implements IOperationBehavior.
Now, in my custom class TokenValidationInvoker, I override Invoke method for my custom validations.

```
public override object Invoke (object instance, object[] inputs, out object[] outputs)
      {
         // Se castea la instancia a AppLogic
         var logic = instance as AppLogic;

         // Comprobar que le primera parámetro es un string
         if (inputs.Length > 0 && inputs[0] is string) {
            // Se intenta validar el token
            logic.ValidateToken (inputs[0] as string);
         } else {
            throw new FaultException ("El método no tiene la signatura correcta");
         }

         // Si no se ha lanzado la excepción, se llama al invocador original
         return originalInvoker.Invoke (instance, inputs, out outputs);
      }
```

This approach works like a charm, if I've decorate a method of my service with [TokenValidationRequired], before the method executing, my validation will be called.

Well... I'm trying to implement NLayer architecture and I want separate the service logic and the business logic and do this validations in BLL (class library).

Is it possible catch method calls in a stardar class library for do something like this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using message inspectors and endpoint/contract behaviors. I have done just this for logging wcf message information.

You will need to define a message inspector. This can be done separately for client proxies and services or as I have defined together.

```
internal class MessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector, IDispatchMessageInspector
{
private void LogMessage(ref msg, bool request)
{
  Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}", received ? "Request" : "Response"));
}

    #region IClientMessageInspector

    public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        LogMessage(ref reply, false);
    }

    public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
    {
        LogMessage(ref request, true);
        return null;
    }

    #endregion

    //Service message inspection        
    #region IDispatchMessageInspector

    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        LogMessage(ref request, true);
        return null;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        LogMessage(ref reply, false);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

The endpoint and contract behaviors

```
internal class LoggingBehavior : IEndpointBehavior, IContractBehavior
{

  #region IEndpointBehavior

    void IEndpointBehavior.AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        ;
    }

    void IEndpointBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        clientRuntime.ClientMessageInspectors.Add(new Inspectors.MessageInspector());
    }

    void IEndpointBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        ;
    }

    void IEndpointBehavior.Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        ;
    }

    #endregion

    #region IContractBehavior

    void IContractBehavior.AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        ;
    }

    void IContractBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        ;
    }

    void IContractBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
    {
        dispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new Inspectors.MessageInspector());
    }

    void IContractBehavior.Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        ;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

After all this is done you will need to modify your services and your service clients.

For services you will need to add a contract behavior to each

```
ServiceHost newService = new ServiceHost(typeof(YourType));
foreach (var endpoint in newService.Description.Endpoints)
{
  endpoint.Contract.ContractBehaviors.Add(new LoggingBehavior());
}
```

And for your proxy client (whose creation I believe you understand quite well)

```
YourTypeClient client = new YourTypeClient();
client.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new Behaviors.LoggingBehavior());
```

This should be everything you need and can be defined in any referenced assembly as the implementations are only dependent upon System.ServiceModel.

Comment: In a service I have my solution and works fine. I want simulate this behavior in a simple class and to do something before the methods calls and to can cancel the method execution.